# In a normed vector space, if $O $ is an open set then $ O+a $ is open?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

In a normed vector space, if $O $ is an open set then $ O+a $ is open? Here $ a$ is an element of some other set $ A $ . This feels intuitively obvious, as we just have "moved" the entire set, but I don't know how to prove it.

Also, if $ O  $ is open and $ < \lambda <1 $ then $ \lambda O $ is open. Again this feels intuitively true.

How can I prove these two statements?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can prove them "by definition". Take $x\in O+a$ and find an open ball in which it lies. Help yourself with the open ball for $x-a$ in $O$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each case, you can define a self-homeomorphism of your space that takes your open set to the desired set. For instance $$v\mapsto v+a$$ is a homeomorphism of your vector space. Since homeomorphisms take open sets to open sets, you are done.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$\lambda B(x, r)=B(\lambda x,\vert\lambda\vert r)$

$a+B(x, r)=B(x+a , r)$

Comment: Here $ B(x+a,r)=\{y:d(y,x+a)<r \} $  ?

Comment: @Alexander: Yes. I made a mistake in typing that euation which is know edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer: You can show that $x \mapsto x + a$ is continuous. Now $O$ is an open set, and $O = (O+a) - a$ is open. Next: what is the definition of continuity in general?